# Is my system using UEFI?

Tags: partition, uefi

I'm installing Gentoo Linux & I don't know if my system uses UEFI or BIOS. 
`ls /sys/firmware` on live cd shows no UEFI file/directory(even after mounting my *boot partition*) so I conclude that it's not using UEFI but on the other hand, while partitioning, after running `set 2 boot on` **esp** flag appears under my boot section in *parted*. So I'm confused which way should I go BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: If you're using kernel newer than 4.0, then you're not booted into UEFI.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克  *uname* says that my kernel version is 4.19.66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UEFI is a type of firmware stored in ROM on the motherboard. The EFI System Partition (ESP) is a specially created partition on a GPT partitioned disk. The ESP can exist on a disk independently of whether the machine has UEFI or BIOS firmware.

Your PC likely does not have UEFI firmware, or if it is a relatively new one, more likely is set to compatibility mode. You can either try to enable UEFI in the firmware setup, or install the operating system in compatibility/BIOS mode. If you do the latter, and your disk has a GPT partition table, you will need to create a [BIOS Boot Partition](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Blocks/Disks/en#What_is_the_BIOS_boot_partition.3F) for GRUB.

Comment: See also http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/ if/when you need to figure out UEFI.